# Swift - Importing Objective-C Gives "Unknown type name"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I'm working on a swift project until i needed [This](https://github.com/ambhojgoyal/TimePicker) "Analog Type Time Picker". I downloaded the repo and tried it using Xcode 6.4 and it works fine. But when I started to transfer it to my project, It ask me to create a Bridging-Header and I created one, Also I imported the .h file in the bridging header. My project can see the delegate method so I think its just fine. But the problem is, the variables on the .m file has an error like this:
[image]
But if you notice, The last `UIButton` don't have error. What do you think seems to be the problem?

Comment: have you imported UIKit to your file?

Comment: @LEVISOGCPAS where did you import it?

Comment: I imported the objective C project that I downloaded to My Swift Project. Specifically the CustomTimePicker.m and CustomTimePicker.h if you check the link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` or `@import UIKit;` at the very top of the .h file where you get these errors

Comment: it should be in the .h, because that is also using a UIView value.

Comment: Jeez! I can't believe i missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It clearly looks like  you do not imported UIKit. Just add `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` or `@import UIKit;` to the top of your .h file.

Answer (score 2):

Otherwise if you are using both combination (Objective-C & Swift) means you need to add bridging header.

Comment: Combined this with @Andrey's answer to fix my issue in a mixed Swift/Objective-c project